# How to use a composer package in CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php, autoload, codeigniter-4

I find many solutions for CI3 on the web, but none works for CI4.

I installed a package using composer

```
composer require chillerlan/php-qrcode
```

Then I added a new Controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;

class Qr extends BaseController
{
    public function index($path)
    {
        $data = 'otpauth://totp/test?secret=B3JX4VCVJDVNXNZ5&issuer=chillerlan.net';

        echo '<img src="' . (new QRCode)->render($data) . '" alt="QR Code" />';
    }
}
```

This gives me `Undefined type 'App\Controllers\QRCode'.` for the `new QRCode`.

What do I need to do, to use the QRCode class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use chillerlan\QRCode\{QROptions, QRCode};

class Qr extends BaseController
{
    public function index($path)
    {
        $data = 'otpauth://totp/test?secret=B3JX4VCVJDVNXNZ5&issuer=chillerlan.net';

        echo '<img src="' . (new QRCode)->render($data) . '" alt="QR Code" />';
    }
}
```